# boost_system renaming and symlink issues on ldd

Tags: gcc, boost, ldd

I have sample application that uses boost_system shared object. Now, because of certain scenarios, I have to support 2 different boost_system shared objects - one built with gcc and other with sun's cc in single directory - /home/mydir. Corresponding files are:-

```
libboost_system_v1.so --dependency for--- applicationv1.so
libboost_system_v2.so --dependency for--- applicationv2.so
```

It is linked in the makefile as.

```
... $(BOOST_LIB_V1) -lboost_system_v1
```

Hence I renamed libboost_system_1_41_0.so to libboost_system_v1.so and also removed the softlink from $BOOST_HOME_V1/stage/lib. Now, when I try to build application - I do not get any errors. However ldd fails with:-

```
ldd /home/mydir/applicationv1.so         
    libboost_system.so.1.41.0 => not found
    .....................................
    .....................................
    .....................................
```

BOOST_HOME_v1/stage/lib(=BOOST_LIB_v1) looks like:-

```
libboost_system_v1.so
libboost_system_v1.a
```

I am unable to understand - why does ldD still show libboost_system.so.1.41.0 as dependency instead of libboost_system_v1.so.

I was expecting to see below o/p **which is not what is obtained**:-

```
ldd /home/mydir/applicationv1.so
     libboost_system_v1.so -> /home/mydir/libboost_system_v1.so
```

Can someone please explain if there is a solution to actually rename shared object and not deal with boost's default symlink? I checked src/build.jam - looks like linkage is done here - but I thought as long as I remove the softlink, rename the shared object and link with renamed shared object in makefile - there shouldn't be any issues.